# Dialog I cannot get rid of

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, spotlight

The steps here were simple, but unexpected:

1. download a file
2. in finder, rename the file using Keyboard:

   1. Press `Enter` to start rename
   2. Start typing a new name (but not pressing `Enter` again)
3. Try to open the file by pressing `Command`-`O`

Now this dialog appears and won't go away (it only reacts on moving with the mouse, but clicking on it fails, just as pressing `Spacebar`, `Enter` or `Esc`).

Both Finder and Spotlight now refuse to open any other file.

I tried:

```
killall -KILL Dock
killall -KILL Finder
killall -KILL NotificationCenter
killall -KILL SystemUIServer
```

Help (:

Note the file is not damaged, just renamed.

[image]

Comment: unless the file is confidential, could you provide the source for it so I can test.

Comment: what happens if you do press enter after tying the new name ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD The file is in a DropBox folder. It synced to another machine where I verified the file is indeed valid, even after the rename synced as well. I didn't even have to press Enter to finish the rename: the switching away from Finder did that for me.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So you are renaming a file that is in the Dropbox folder. What happens if you move it out of it, just to see if it has anything to do with the sync link.

Comment: Didn't help. The dialog was blocking for any PDF to open in finder. Probably a bug somewhere. Killing the process under it solves the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search for [OS X identify process by window](https://www.google.com/search?q=OS%20X%20identify%20process%20by%20window) I found [What process owns a certain window (Mac OS X)](http://blog.loudhush.ro/2014/04/what-process-owns-certain-window-mac-os.html) which told me this after moving the Window:

```
RetinaMBPro1TB:bin jeroenp$ ./show-recently-moved-windows.py 
Move target window

List of windows that moved:
{(
        {
        kCGWindowAlpha = 1;
        kCGWindowBounds =         {
            Height = 1094;
            Width = 1130;
            X = 43;
            Y = 45;
        };
        kCGWindowIsOnscreen = 1;
        kCGWindowLayer = 0;
        kCGWindowMemoryUsage = 5246548;
        kCGWindowName = "bin \U2014 Python \U2014 160\U00d776";
        kCGWindowNumber = 23921;
        kCGWindowOwnerName = Terminal;
        kCGWindowOwnerPID = 357;
        kCGWindowSharingState = 1;
        kCGWindowStoreType = 2;
    },
        {
        kCGWindowAlpha = 1;
        kCGWindowBounds =         {
            Height = 153;
            Width = 420;
            X = 1359;
            Y = 182;
        };
        kCGWindowIsOnscreen = 1;
        kCGWindowLayer = 8;
        kCGWindowMemoryUsage = 390292;
        kCGWindowName = "";
        kCGWindowNumber = 23246;
        kCGWindowOwnerName = CoreServicesUIAgent;
        kCGWindowOwnerPID = 87976;
        kCGWindowSharingState = 1;
        kCGWindowStoreType = 2;
    }
)}
```

Since [`CoreServicesUIAgent`](https://www.google.com/search?q=CoreServicesUIAgent) is the owner, I performed this:

```
killall -KILL CoreServicesUIAgent
```

That worked. Now I can open the PDF again.

Comment: "killall -KILL CoreServicesUIAgent" helped in another freezed process thx

Answer (score 0):

The icon in the dialog box is the clue. It's something to do with Gatekeeper. This article from Apple https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202491 might help.

Comment: The icons look the same, but it looks gatekeeper is about applications (.PDF open in the stock Preview applications which is from Apple). My settings are pretty default: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmbc6004h0s5n7m/Screenshot%202015-07-21%2006.21.39.png?dl=0